# rails model before_update can't access current_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to update the inspector_id in table Tasks with the employee_id of the current user.  But, the model won't let me access current_user.

This is the code I'm trying to use in the Task model.

```
before_update :update_inspector

protected
 def update_inspector
  self.inspector_id = current_user.employee
 end
```

I get:

```
NameError (undefined local variable or method `current_user'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically current_user is defined in the application controller. This means that the method is only available inside controllers, not models. The error you are seeing is consistent with that state of affairs. If you need the current_user in the Task model, you'll have to pass it in somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You could always access the session information that built the current_user variable inside of the model.